# Golang date time struct

Tags: json, go, bson

I'm trying to build golang date time struct and I'm having some issues. Please help me build the model.

Thanks again

```
 "effectiveDates" : {
    "startDate" : {
        "_class" : "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl", 
        "year" : NumberInt(2008), 
        "month" : NumberInt(10), 
        "day" : NumberInt(16), 
        "timezone" : NumberInt(-300), 
        "hour" : NumberInt(9), 
        "minute" : NumberInt(50), 
        "second" : NumberInt(13)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard libraries `Time` object? It already has all this. https://golang.org/pkg/time/

Comment: The objects are being built by another process and being dumped into mongoDB. I'm trying to build a GET golang service for retrieval. Currently, I have no control over the POST.

Comment: I'm unable to use http://json2struct.mervine.net/ or https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ for conversion and I can't figure out how to build.

Comment: You should still just use `Time` everywhere and then create an instance of the model right before you post to the API. Is that supposed to be the json in your question? What is the body of the post supposed to be?

Comment: This is the JSON data that exists in my MongoDB. I'm trying to perform a GET function but I'm unsure how to build the Go "struct"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be enough to get you going.  There are a couple quirks:

- The NumberInt(n) values are not valid JSON, so I've assumed they come in from the GET call as a number
- The timezone NumberInt will need to be converted to a string, and massaged into the form -0700.  I've left that as an exercise for you

Here's my solution:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type StartDate struct {
    Class    string `json:"_class"`
    Year     int `json:"year"`
    Month    int `json:"month"`
    Day      int `json:"day"`
    Timezone string `json:"timezone"`
    Hour     int `json:"hour"`
    Minute   int `json:"minute"`
    Second   int `json:"second"`
}

type EffectiveDates struct {
    StartDate `json:"startDate"`
}

type Payload struct {
    EffectiveDates `json:"effectiveDates"`
}

var input = `{ 
  "effectiveDates" : {
     "startDate" : {
        "_class" : "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl", 
        "year" : 2008, 
        "month" : 10, 
        "day" : 16, 
        "timezone" : "-0300", 
        "hour" : 9, 
        "minute" : 50, 
        "second" : 13
     }
  }
}`

func main() {
    var p Payload
    var t time.Time
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input[:]), &p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    timeStr := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s", p.Year, p.Month, p.Day, p.Hour, p.Minute, p.Second, p.Timezone)
    if t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02 3:04:05 -0700", timeStr); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", t.Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. Tested, verified and works as expected.